# Race Condition in Mesa Monitor

Tags: operating-systems, concurrency, synchronization, threads, c

```
global volatile RingBuffer queue; 
global Lock queueLock;      
global CV queueEmptyCV;     
global CV queueFullCV;

public method producer() {
    while (true) {
        task myTask = ...; // Producer makes some new task to be added.
        queueLock.acquire();

        while (queue.isFull()) { //####
            wait(queueLock, queueFullCV);
        }
        queue.enqueue(myTask);
        signal(queueEmptyCV); -- OR -- notifyAll(queueEmptyCV);
        
        queueLock.release(); 
    }
}

public method consumer() {
    while (true) {
        queueLock.acquire();

        while (queue.isEmpty()) { 
            wait(queueLock, queueEmptyCV);
        }
        myTask = queue.dequeue(); 
        signal(queueFullCV); -- OR -- notifyAll(queueFullCV); //###

        queueLock.release(); 
        doStuff(myTask); // Go off and do something with the task.
    }
}
```

This is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization).
I have tried a lot but I cannot understand that when `notifyAll(queueFullCV)` is called at `//###` why is there not a race condition in while loop of `//####`.
I can easily see many treads taking off and then, since `while (queue.isFull())` is false at that instant, go and `queue.enqueue(myTask)` more than capacity.

//OR//

Can only one tread at a time acquire the queueLock, and after one `queue.enqueue(myTask)`, when the other's turn comes `while (queue.isFull())` is full and then go back to sleep again?
In that case, what is the need for `notifyAll(queueFullCV)` when only one tread would get the queueLock?